# How to print a Wpf components

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

I want to print a Framework element on a paper.

I'm currently having this:

```
    public static void Print(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
            return;
        frameworkElement.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
        frameworkElement.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), frameworkElement.DesiredSize));
        dialog.PrintVisual(frameworkElement, "A Great Image.");
    }
```

but with this, my components doesn't takes the whole page, which is normal, because we ask him to paint with his desired size.

My second question about printing:

Can I do ONE print task, but print several components(one on each page?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PrintDocument class.

[Example](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9cbb4841-8677-49e9-a3a8-46031e699b2e/wpf-printing-and-print-pr.aspx)